# html content is not sent in email

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

I want to sent the link to the email so when user clicks that link, the user will be redirected to the refer page and can refer other friends. I have used send_mail to send the email. Everything gets sent except the html message. Here is what i have done

```
  if created:
     new_join_old.invite_code = get_invite_code()
     new_join_old.save()
     subject = "Thank you for your request to sign up our community"
     html_message = '<a href="http://localhost:8000/{% url "invitations:refer-invitation" invite_code %}">Click Here</a>'
     message = "Welcome! We will be in contact with you."
     from_email = None
     to_email = [email]
     send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
     messages.success(request, '{0} has been invited'.format(email))
   return HttpResponseRedirect("/invitations/refer-invitation/%s"%(new_join_old.invite_code))
context = {"form": form}
return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Comment: If you're testing it locally in debug mode, you see the message in the console without the HTML part, right?

Comment: Have you tried this: `html_message = '<a href="http://localhost:8000{}">Click Here</a>'.format(reverse('invitations:refer-invitation', kwrags={'invite_code': invite_code}))` ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: nup its not working. Still only html message is not sent

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATE]**: In order for the below to work you must have set then appropriate [email settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#email-host) inside your `settings.py` file, like this:

```
# settings.py

#######################
#   EMAIL SETTINGS    #
#######################
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email_username_here'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'email_password_here'
```

The `<a>` link is not rendered because there is no `loader` to render it (unknown `{% url %}` template tag). If you like to preserve this syntax (`{% url ... %}`) and have a separate HTML file that will be sent then store the HTML file as separate file, say `html_email.html` and then use [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) and do the following:

```
<!-- html_email.html -->

<a href="http://localhost:8000/{% url 'invitations:refer-invitation' invite_code %}">Click Here</a>


# views.py

from django.template.loader import render_to_string

if created:
    # above code as is
    # in the context you can pass other context variables that will be available inside the html_email.html
    context = {'invite_code': new_join_old.invite_code,}
    html_message = render_to_string('path/to/html_email.html', context=context)
    # below code as is
```

or you can do it this way:

```
#views.py

from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.urls import reverse

if created:
    # above code as is
    html_message = '<a href="http://localhost:8000{}">Click Here</a>'.format(reverse('invitations:refer-invitation', kwrags={'invite_code': invite_code}))
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')
    msg.send()
```

Comment: I did this already_join.save()
            subject = "Thank you for your request to sign up our community"
            context = {'invite_code': already_join.invite_code}
            html_message = render_to_string('email_templates/email.html', context=context)
            message = "Welcome! We will be in contact with you."
            from_email = None
            to_email = [email]
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message) but is not working yet. Subject and message is sent but not html_message

Comment: @pythonLover Updated my answer with the appropriate email settings that must be set. Are you sure are set? Because I just tested it and works.

Comment: sorry for late response. I am using celery for asynchrnonous task queue. I have updated my question with celery code and i am using MAILGUN.

Comment: I think I am missing something in my EmailBackend. It is still not working.

Comment: Inside the `EmailBackend`'s `__init__` method change to this: `super().__init__(self, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138638/discussion-between-pythonlover-and-nik-m).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.template import Context, Template

email_data = open('email_templates/email.html', 'r').read()
html_data = Template(email_data)
html_content = html_data.render(Context({'invite_code': new_join_old.invite_code}))
```

You can add `message`,`subject` etc key-value pair in context as well

In email.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/invitations/refer-invitation/{{ invite_code }}">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You can access the value of context variable like `message` and `subject` in email.html using `{{ message }}` and `{{ subject }}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class